# Will hibernate create new session upon nesting a REQUIRES_NEW transaction?

Tags: hibernate, spring-transactions

```
transactionalMethod() {
   Model model = service.fetch()
   nestedTransactionalMethod(model) //REQUIRES_NEW transaction
}
```

In the code snippet above, will the nestedTransactionalMethod() create a new session? That means the model passed to it is dettached?

Are these assumptions correct?

Answer (score 0):

PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW uses an independent transaction for each affected transaction scope. In that case, the underlying physical transactions are different and hence can commit or roll back independently, with an outer transaction not affected by an inner transaction's rollback status. 
And it will not create a new session, rather it will use the current session to create the new transaction as defined by the propagation scope.